# Generate large dataset for a line chart

Tags: json, random, dataset

I need to test graphing application on a big data set. Data is in `json` format with the structure:

```
{
 "linechart":[
  {
   "x":[5,15,20,3],
   "y":[10,20,30,40]
  }
 ]
}
```

4 numbers represents 1 line, i.e. `x[i]` and `y[i]` is start point, while `x[i+1]` and `y[i+1]` is end point.

I want a chart to be inseparable (i.e. without "gaps"). By "big data set" i mean `json` of `~50mb` as a perfect case, though it's not critical, the goal is to have at least a few thousand of points.

It is not possible to produce it manually and I can't think of any solution to this.

Comment: Just randomly generate x random numbers, copy them and paste them in your json. Do the same for y. I don't see what the difficulty is here. There is even an online website to do this: https://numbergenerator.org/randomnumbergenerator#!numbers=5&low=1&high=100&unique=true&csv=csv&oddeven=&start=false

Comment: What do you mean by "inseparable"? Your parenthetical definition is vague. If you are going to do this programmatically, you have to have a definition which is clear enough that it can be programmed.